# Issue with restricting download from Exchange 2019 OWA

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app

Have an on premise Exchange 2019 server. Trying to restrict OWA users from downloading attachments. All online documentation I have found says to disable direct file download to both public and private computers. I did this using the PowerShell commands. However, it doesn't appear to work. Users can still choose to save an attachment when logged into OWA. Anyone else seen this? Know where I messed up? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We could use the following command to disable it:

Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -DirectFileAccessOnPublicComputersEnabled $false -DirectFileAccessOnPrivateComputersEnabled $false

It took about 2 mins to finish running this. To confirm that all is complete, you can run Get-OwaMailboxPolicy and check if they should both be set to False.

Did you test with other users?
You also could check if the policy had been assigned to certain users.

Comment: That is what I tried and it still doesn't stop the users from downloading attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I was able to use   Set-OwaVirtualDirectory -Identity "Contoso\owa (default Web site)" -DirectFileAccessOnPrivateComputersEnabled $false and it now blocks OWA users from downloading files. Unfortunately there is no way to allow them to preview files. I believe you can do that with Exchange Online/365.

Comment: Glad to know the OWA download is working now. “Unfortunately there is no way to allow them to preview files. I believe you can do that with Exchange Online/365.”, yes, they can use Office Online. If the answer is helpful please mark it as ANSWER.